# Filter entries in the Eclipse Variables View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any built-in way (or plug-in) allowing for searching through the whole variable tree without manually expanding nodes?

I can't understand why isn't it done by default, just as I can't understand, why isn't search bar built into Variables view (browser style) and this unhandy, inconvenient dialog is opened instead. It makes my work, which is mainly debugging complex applications, a nightmare.

The Eclipse version is Luna, if it matters.

The watch expression feature is not what I want *because it just doesn't work in this case, tried to fix it but none of the common ways to do that help me.*

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature has been requested earlier here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=170396

You may want to reopen this bug to state your interest in this enhancement. And if you have experience in developing Eclipse IDE plug-ins, I am sure the maintainers would be happy to review a patch.

I usually use <kbd>Alt+Shift+Right</kbd>/<kbd>Alt+Shift+Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> to select and inspect variables and expressions, but this certainly depends on personal preferences.